# Download every nth node overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, query, overpass-api

I would like to download OSM Data of admin borders and highways for a very large area. This would produce a very large file and is way too much for the osm overpass (I used overpass turbo but am happy to use another program (such as QuickOSM in QGIS) if that is the solution). I therefore wanted to only query for every n-th (example: 1000th) node of an object. How to I specify this in my query? I tried `n%1000`, which gave me an error.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use Overpass Turbo?  If you just want "simplified boundaries" then some other combination of tools may work better to get that data from OSM, or even the (non-OSM) Natural Earth data,

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported by Overpass API. You can try to create a feature request on https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API